# Android:calling Reminder option

Tags: android, android-fragments, alarmmanager, reminders

I have been searching the internet for an hour trying to find out how to call a reminder.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179251/android-how-to-create-reminder-alarm-in-application refere this once

Comment: i already found thanx

Answer (score 0):

I have found answer by myself

on onclick

```
remindTxt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            // cal.setTime(new
            // SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss").parse(givenDateString));
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
            intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
            intent.putExtra("beginTime", cal.getTimeInMillis());
            intent.putExtra("allDay", false);
            intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
            intent.putExtra("endTime",
                    cal.getTimeInMillis() + 60 * 60 * 1000);
            intent.putExtra("title", " Test Title");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```